# Reading ReadSubtree()'s entire string before calling XElement.Load()

Tags: c#, xml, debugging, exception, xml-parsing

I'm using the following code to read xml subtrees from a stream (where reader is an XmlReader):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   using (XmlReader subTreeReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
   {
      try
      {
         XElement xmlData = XElement.Load(subTreeReader);
         ProcessStreamingEvent(xmlData);
      }
      catch (XmlException ex)
      {                                        
        // want to write xml subtree
      }
   }
}
```

It works fine most of the time, but once XElement.Load(subTreeReader) throws an exception like

> Name cannot begin with the '[' character, hexadecimal value 0x5B. Line
>   1, position 775.

The message is mostly useless; I need to output the entire string that XElement.Load() tried to parse. How can I do this? In the exception handler there is very little information; subTreeReader.Nodetype is Text, and Value is "spread". Perhaps I need to read the content of subTreeReader before calling XElement.Load()? It seems like subTreeReader should contain the entire string since it knows where the tree ends...?

I tried to replace XElement xmlData = XElement.Load(subTreeReader) with:

```
string xmlString = subTreeReader.ReadOuterXml();
XElement xmlData = XElement.Load(xmlString);
```

but xmlString is empty (even when subTreeReader does contain valid xml).

Interesting (and a good thing) that it is not XmlReader.Read() or XmlReader.ReadSubTree() that throws an exception (when the stream may not contain xml), but rather XElement.Load(). Makes me wonder though how does ReadSubTree() knows when to stop reading when the stream the does not contain xml.

Comment: Square brackets normally indicate a json string, not pure xml.  The xml may be wrapped in a [CData] object.

Comment: You might be right; however, to process that json, I would still need a string representation of whatever XElement.Load() was trying to parse so I can hand it off to a json parser...?

Comment: Use a Jason method to deserialize instead of and xml method.  You can extract the xml from the Jason, but trying with just xml will cause an exception.

Comment: The stream almost always only contains xml, not json. Once in a while a json object shows up. Is there a way to hand over this part of the stream to a json parser? Again, it seems like I would need the string that XElement.Load() tried to parse.

Comment: Try XmlTextReader instead of XmlReader.  I've seen cases where the XmlTextReader works better.